# How do I create an ROC curve using pROC?

Tags: r, roc

I have a table of data that gives me the number of people with a certain disease and the number of people without this disease. Using this data, how can I use pROC or ROCR to construct an ROC curve? Basically, I don't know how to put my data into a form that the roc function accepts. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: ROC curves are used to visualize classifier performance.  The data table needs more than "the number of people with a certain disease and the number of people without this disease".  In addition to the number with and without the disease, you would need a classifier's confidence that each observation belongs to a certain class.  pROC is very straight forward after that. You need to provide more information for a more specific answer.

Comment: You should look at their [paper](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/77). This question is off topic here.

Answer (score 4):

An ROC curve is used for judging the accuracy of a binary classifier.  Therefore for each data point you should not only have $y_i \in \{0, 1\}$, but also a value $\hat{y}_i \in [0,1]$ which should be higher if you believe more strongly that the value of $y_i$ is 1.  An ROC curve is then obtained by looping through all (essentially all) possible thresholds $t$ and setting $z_i = 1$ if $\hat{y}_i > t$, else $z_i = 0$, and computing the False Positive Rate and True Positive Rate for each value $t$.

What I mean to say is, if all you have is the true labels $y_i$, it does not make sense to try and create an ROC curve.